# Different environments in different shells

Tags: bash, zsh

Suppose for the sake of simplicity that I am working with bash and zsh. In bash, I have a `.bash_profile` that puts `~/bash/bin` in the PATH, and in zsh, I have in my `.zshrc` the path `~/zsh/bin` in the PATH. Now, suppose I have two executables at `~/bash/bin/foobar` and `~/zsh/bin/foobar`. As such, if I run `command -v foobar`, I should be returning one of the two, depending if I was working in bash or zsh. The question I have is as follows: is it possible to, in a bash script, determine what `command -v foobar` would output  in zsh, or vice-versa?

I'm not confident that

```
#!/bin/bash
zsh -c 'command -v foobar'
```

would give me the output of `~/zsh/bin/foobar` in this case.

Comment: Why not? What exactly are the failure scenarios you envision? I'm not familiar enough with Zsh to say whether that works without modification; for Bash, the results for interactive vs noninteractive and login vs non-login shells could be different, so make sure you call it with the right flags if you want e.g. interactive non-login shell behavior even if you are querying it from a noninteractive and/or login shell.

Comment: I find the split between `bash/bin` and `zsh/bin` odd.  Who cares what language the commands in `bin` are written in?

Comment: @KelvinChung : It would output the same as in bash. Since you use `zsh -c`, zsh simply inherits the `PATH` variable from bash. To really see any difference, you would have to empty your environment in bash and then do a, say, `zsh -l -i -c "...."`.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
zsh -c 'command -v foobar'
```

does not process ~/.zshrc , so you can't expect any effect of this file on this command. You could do a

```
zsh -i -c 'command -v foobar'
```

to force .zshrc to be processed, but this does not **necessarily** mean that you would see here a different directory. For instance, assume that in your bash, the PATH is set to `/usr/bin:$HOME/bash/bin`, and your .zshrc sets the PATH by doing a

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/zsh/bin
```

In this case, even `zsh -i -c ....` would still show *$HOME/bash/bin/foobar* as a match.